# Handle orientation change for fields

Tags: blackberry, screen-orientation

I would like to adapt my app to handle both portrait and landscape orientation. I use `sublayout()` to check if the orientation has changed, if yes i remove all the fields and then add all the fields again. So all the fields layout properly for the new display width. I dont like this solution, so I was wondering if there was an elegant solution to layout fields properly.

Comment: IMHO, if you use Managers and alignment flags, you hardly need to do anything. Definitely not removing them and adding the fields again.

Comment: How would i resize the custom fields then?

Answer (score 2):

Override your custom fields `getPreferedWidth()` via scaling `Display.getWidth` and `getPreferedHeight()` via scaling`Display.getHeight()` and if you override `paint(Graphics g)`  use  `getPreferedWidth()` and `getPreferedHeight()` inside method body.

Answer (score 0):

In Blackberry when we change screen orientation `sublayout()` method is called for the current Screen .When u change the Orienation do not delete any field . It will become complex to manage `Delete/Add` any field . Just Manage your Screen layout dynamically using `Display.getwidth()` & `Display.getheight()` as reference and keep resize background Image of the `Screen`.